# SSRS reportViewer and async processing

Tags: c#, multithreading, reportviewer

I am working on some old ReportViewer code. It has been working fine for years but a blocking issue has been discovered and I am trying to implement async processing. Getting errors. Let me show relevant code.
ASPX page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Async="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReprtViewer.aspx.cs" Inherits="PrismWeb.reports.ExportFDReportsExcel" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
<script>
    function onBodyLoad() {
        document.getElementById("ExportBtn").click();
    }
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height: 100%">
    <div style="display: none">
        <asp:Button ID="ExportBtn" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="ExportBtn_OnClick" />
    </div>
    <div style="height: 0; width: 0; overflow: hidden;">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>
                <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hfFileExportStatus" value="0" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%" EnableTelemetry="false">
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </div>
</form>
```

ReportViewer.aspx.cs

```
protected async void ExportBtn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(new                
    System.Security.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted));
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    var rep = ReportViewer1.LocalReport;
    var repDef = repService.GetReportDefinition(reportId);
}
await Task.Run(() =>
{
try
{
     var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
     var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);
     sw.Write(repDef.ToString());
     sw.Flush();
     ms.Position = 0;
     rep.LoadReportDefinition(ms);
     ms.Close();
     ....
```

I get an error at the line **rep.LoadReportDefinition(ms);**
The error is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Viewer control object is in a read only state at 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.EnsureUnlocked() at 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.OnReportChanged(Object sender, 
ReportChangedEventArgs e) at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) at 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Report.OnChange(Boolean isRefreshOnly) at 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.ChangeReportDefinition(DefinitionSource 
updatingSourceType, Action changeAction) at 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(TextReader report) at 
PrismWeb.reports.ReportViwer.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0()
```

Like I said without async everything works fine. Any ideas to share?

Thanks

Comment: WebForms isn't very `async` friendly, it's obsolete for a reason after all.

Comment: I am not a c# developer. What else could I use?

Comment: Just don't use `async`, and probably not threads either. It looks like you're trying to read a file, just do it in your handler and call it a day.

Comment: Well, without async I am facing a blocking issue when a second report request comes in from the same browser session.

Comment: Debug that then, individual requests don't block each other unless you starve the main thread pool (with `Task.Run` for example, a gigantic red arrow to fire whoever put that in a WebForms application immediately).

Comment: Starving the main thread pool further isn't going to improve anything, unless you just make the application crash, thus freeing the thread pool faster.

Comment: The blocking issue is happening because some reports are taking a long time to process.

Comment: @Mark - Are you disposing those streams?

Comment: Hmm, probably no.

Comment: @Mark - That could well be your blocking issue. You might be running out of system resources.

Comment: @Enigmativity. Isn't ms.Close(); dispose the stream?

Comment: @Mark - Yes, but you should always get into a habit of disposing every single disposable always, without exception, except for `HttpClient`.